# The grammatical nature of "mondai naku"

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> でも今は問題なく食べることができます
> Demo ima wa mondai naku taberu koto ga dekimasu"

what is the grammatical nature of "mondai naku"? Is it a noun, an adjective or an adverb?

Comment: Do you understand the sentence? What are your own thoughts?

Comment: Yeah. The sentence can be translated as: "but now i am able to eat it without any problem".

Answer (score 2):

It's *adverbial*, i.e., it modifies a verb. In general, the ku-form of an adjective is also known as the adverbial form.

- この車は速**く**走る。(adverbial)
  This car runs *fast*.
- 速**い**電車 (adjectival)
  a *fast* car

ない is a bit special in that it can take certain nouns and work like a suffix meaning "-less(ly)", but the resulting phrase is still grammatically an adjective, so its ku-form is adverbial. You can think 問題ない is a [distinct adjective](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84).

Similar example:

- 変わりない日々
  uneventful days
- 変わりなく日々を過ごしています。
  I spend days uneventfully.

Comment: Out of the options given it would have to be 'adverb'  but is there anything to stop the answer being 'verb', i.e. negative, continuative form of ある: "It's not a problem now, and I can eat it"?

Comment: @user3856370 You need a comma to force that parsing strategy because the adverbial reading makes perfect sense. Besides, ない is  an adjective (or adjective-like auxiliary) anyway, not a form of ある.

Comment: @naruto thank you

Answer (score 1):

One note is that I feel that なく in cases like this can simply be a shorter and more formal form of なくて if that helps...

So your sentence can also be written as "でも今は問題（が）なくて、食べることができます".